# Error Reading Track from ID3V1 Tag

Tags: c, struct, id3

I am currently trying to read information from an ID3V1.1 tag in C. For this project we are not allowed to use any external libraries. All of the fields except for the track field read correctly. The last two lines are the ones giving me trouble. Whenever I run the program, I get a seg fault when it tries to get the track number. I tried to debug using gdb and it said the problem was happening on line 34 which is where the fseek is. It works for the other fields so I'm wondering why it is going wrong. Should I change the offset to something other than -128? But the whole tag is only 128 characters so I'm unsure what is going wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Tag
{
        char tag[3];
        char song_title[30];
        char artist[30];
        char album[30];
        char year[4];
        char comment[28];
        char seperator;
        char track;
        char genre;
};

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
        struct Tag file_tag;
        FILE *fp;
        char title[31];
        char artist[31];
        char album[31];
        char year[5];
        char comment[29];
        char track[2];
        int track_number;

        fp = fopen(argv[1],"r+b");
        if (!fp)
        {
                printf("File does not exist");
        }
    fseek(fp, -128, SEEK_END);
        fread(&file_tag,sizeof(file_tag),1,fp);
        fclose(fp);
        if(strncmp(file_tag.tag,"TAG",3)!=0)
        {
                printf("ID3 tag is not present\n");
        }
    else
    {
                strncpy(title, file_tag.song_title,30);
                title[31]='\0';
                printf("Title: %s\n",title);
                strncpy(artist, file_tag.artist,30);
                artist[31]='\0';
                printf("Artist: %s\n",artist);

                strncpy(album, file_tag.album,30);
                album[31]='\0';
                printf("Album: %s\n",album);

                strncpy(year, file_tag.year,4);
                year[4]='\0';
                printf("Year: %s\n",year);
                //printf("Year: %.4s\n",file_tag.year);

                strncpy(comment, file_tag.comment,28);
                comment[29]='\0';
                printf("Comment: %s\n",comment);
                //these lines cause the seg fault
                track_number = atoi(file_tag.track);
                printf("Track: %d\n",track_number);

        }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the full information of the segFault:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000034ff66edf1 in fseek () from /lib64/libc.so.6
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.12-1.132.el6_5.3.x86_64
(gdb) back
#0  0x00000034ff66edf1 in fseek () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x000000000040076f in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdf58) at id3tagEd.c:34
```

Comment: can you try with SEEK_SET and SEEK_END without offsets to find the whether your file is shorten than expected?

Comment: Yes, it is confirmed that the tag exists in the last 128 characters of the file. So the track should be in there but I'm not sure what's going on. The file is the size I have expected

Comment: It looks like `file_tag.track` should be null-terminated before passing it to `atoi`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is a little too late, but if anyone have this same problem,when you did the fread you give it the size of the file_tag instead of a Tag. I changed it and it worked.